# Problems with Push Notifications on Server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, push

I am facing a weird problem with push notifications on Chrome and Firefox. I have created a push notification service in a similar fashion to the recent tutorials on this issue (such as https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications), using an index.js javascript page to register the service, which for the sake of argument is named mypushservice.js. Both are located in the same folder on my web server.
The registration works fine in my development environment, and when I deploy the files on my (SSL) production server environment and call the index.js from a different test location, the registration seems to work fine as well. 
However, upon integration of the application with the product that needs to utilise the push notification service, the

navigator.serviceWorker.register('./mypushservice.js')

fails with a 404 not found Http exception. The javascript file is available (and can be registered from my test location), but somehow the service fails when called from another environment.

Has anyone had similar issues and found a solution for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution to this problem. Apparently the index.js and mypushservice.js both need to be accessed from the same server in order to work. The call to index.js was made from another (client) server, which created a security problem. We managed to create a workaround by adding an html page to the server that calls index.js on loading, and embedding this html file in an IFrame from the client server. I am still looking for a neater solution, but for now this works fine